# Load a specific subview into a container with superview's button

Tags: ios, button, subview

I'm building an app that should be able to load different subviews into a container in the main view like so:
[image: storyboard]

When the light green view loads, the yellow view should be displayed inside the container. (Ignore the buttons at the top of the yellow view. In the real thing, they shouldnt be there at all)

The app will store a value remembering which view should be loaded if the user presses either "play local" or "play youtube". If the user presses "play local" then one of the orange/blue/light blue should be loaded, and if they press "play youtube" the dark/brown/purple view should be loaded.

If the clear button is pressed, the container should display the yellow view again.

How can I get the buttons in the green controller to reference the views to be displayed inside the Container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement prepareForSegue in the green controller. That will be called right after it is instantiated because of its embed segue to the navigation controller.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSURLRequest *)sender {
    UINavigationController *nav = segue.destinationViewController;
    self.yellow = nav.topViewController; // yellow is a property pointing to your yellow view controller;
}
```

Now, in your button methods, you can just call whichever segue you want based on your logic,

```
[self.yellow preformSegueWithIdentifier:@"Orange" sender:self];
```

Comment: I understand. Part of my problem is with getting the properties to show up at all. For example, where do I put the property called yellow? If I try to ctrl click and drag to my main ViewController.h file, it doesn't do anything. I assume I need to create a new file, but I don't know where to put it and how to tie it in.

Comment: @marisbest2, I don't know why that didn't work. That property can be put in either the .h or .m file (in the class extension) of the green controller.

Comment: sorry I had misunderstood. Now I have a problem that when I call preformSegueWithIdentifier:sender: I'm pushing onto the nav stack which can't be too big and it gets stuck.

Comment: @marisbest2, I have no idea what you mean by "nav stack which can't be too big and it gets stuck".

Comment: if I use performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: then the next view gets add to the views stack. If I keep adding views to the stack, it'll eventually stop me from adding new views to the stack, or so it seems. I can click the buttons and load the Orange and Blue views, but then if I click twice, it reloads the view, and if I click the buttons too many times, it stops letting me perform segues. I tried popping back to root, but that just left me with a blank white screen

Answer (score 0):

Write the following code in the function which will be called on the button press.

```
   UIStoryboard* storyboard = [self storyboard];
        PlayLocalViewController *yourView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayeLocalControllerID"];                                                        //yourViewis the ViewController object
        yourView.view.frame = self.yourContainerView.bounds;
                               //youContainerView is the containerView property.
        [self.yourContainerView addSubview:yourView.view];
        [self addChildViewController:yourView];
        [yourView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```